# Pandas Dataframe mask based on row number/index

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
        Index     Open     High      Low    Close
0  2016-01-22  7355.70  7433.40  7327.60  7422.45
1  2016-01-25  7468.75  7487.15  7421.20  7436.15
2  2016-01-27  7469.60  7477.90  7419.70  7437.75
3  2016-01-28  7426.50  7468.85  7409.60  7424.65
4  2016-01-29  7413.35  7575.65  7402.80  7563.55
5  2016-02-01  7589.50  7600.45  7541.25  7555.95
6  2016-02-02  7566.65  7576.30  7428.05  7455.55
7  2016-02-03  7392.45  7419.40  7350.30  7361.80
8  2016-02-04  7411.45  7457.05  7365.95  7404.00
9  2016-02-05  7418.25  7503.15  7406.65  7489.10
```

I want to be able to add an Column, 'Indicator' which will have the value '0' for the first few rows defined by variable 'period'.

Comment: "I want to be able to add an Column, 'Indicator' which will have the value '0' for the first few rows defined by variable 'period'." can you please elaborate? This isn't very clear as it stands.

Comment: Add a new column, 'Indicator'. For value of df['Indicator'] for the first few rows should be 0. For the rest, it will be (df['Open'] + df['Close'].shift(1))/2.       

Still getting to understand the formatting in SO and hence having difficulty in illustrating. Apologies!

Comment: @Madhavan it will help if you specify the range of first few row. As you mentioned that for first few rows value of column "indicator" should be 0. for this we need to what will be condition statement which will define first few rows. so for those rows we can set value 0 and for rest of rows as you mentioned above.